# How to select nested ul element using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

For something seemingly simple, it's causing me some trouble.

I have the following pattern:

```
    <div className="row">
      <ul className="col-md-4 options-ul">
```

Question is how do i select the nested ul using plain javascript? I've tried various renditions of querySelector and querySelectorAll to no avail. tia

Comment: I do not know if there are othet things with the same class, if you want to select them all, or not, etc... however, get the code in your browser, open developer tools, right click on the element, and select copy selector. That should get you started. *Unless you are using old edge or worse.*

Comment: @Theraot you're right. based on the browser code, i think i'm dealing with something unexpected -- a pseudo element that seems invisible to querySelector. other threads show it's not an easy fix. AngelPolitis, Christian- thanks for closing a few doors for me in my search. i'll post up a fix and links if i find one that makes sense.

Comment: "a pseudo element that seems invisible to querySelector", hmm... see [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if your question has been answered sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector(".options-ul")` after you switch your `className` attribute to `class`.

If, for some reason, you need to use `classname` (HTML attributes are lower case):

```
document.querySelector("[classname ~= 'options-ul']");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".row > ul")
```

to get the immediate `ul` child of every `.row` element. Use `document.querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll` if you just want the first result.